# Python - how select/drop elements in data frames that have multiple (2) indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python data frame (test) with 2 indices (permKey and ccy)

```
              qty  inventoryValue
permKey ccy                     
CASH    AUD    3           60000
        USD    3            1200
SPY     USD    5            1050
```

To select all cash positions, this code does the job:

```
Cash = test.loc['CASH']
```

How do I select all non CASH related positions (there can be many) - i.e. what is the command to drop the cash positions in this df?

I tried something like this

```
nonCash = test.drop(test.loc['CASH'], axis=1)
```

but it results in an empty data frame

```
test Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(CASH, AUD), (CASH, USD), (SPY, USD)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like it was just use the drop statement differently

```
nonCash = test.drop(['CASH'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the first level of your index and create a boolean array of the non-cash indices:

```
nonCash = test.index.levels[0] != 'CASH'
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then use the nonCash array as a filter for your DataFrame:

```
test[nonCash]
            qty  intentoryValue
permKey ccy                     
SPY     USD    5            1050
```

Comment: This does not work. test.index.levels[0] != 'CASH' only gives an array of 2 values False, True and then results in error messages when executing test[nonCash] as it expects three values